DolphinAPI Max retries exceeded with url
I am using a proxy on Dolphin Anty browser. It runs my other function no issues with commands but when it gets to the 2nd function I get this error below

HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=51002): Max retries exceeded
with url: /session/d86ddcdf2886bdd5f626ab1675a0210b/element (Caused by
NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
0x0000012DA5990350>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError
10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively
refused it'))

from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import selenium_dolphin as dolphin
from selenium_dolphin import DolphinAPI, STABLE_CHROME_VERSION
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import random
import string
import pyautogui
import tweepy
import time
import re
import openai
from openai import OpenAI

def openn():
    sleep(2)
    api = DolphinAPI('')
    response = api.get_profiles()
    response = dolphin.run_profile('376839741')
    port = response['automation']['port']
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    global driver
    driver = dolphin.get_driver(options, port)
    sleep(10)
    print('Opened Dolphin')

def dmactions():
    print("Searching for title")
    sleep(5)
    dmurl = driver.current_url #stores the dm page
    print("stored")



I tried changing the function and whatever I change any actions gets this message
